# Update several Eclipse-RCP applications using p2

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2, auto-update

I have to prepare PCs for offline use.

I'm looking for a solution to update several different Eclipse-RCP applications on a PC from a central p2 repository without starting each application manually.

The idea is to provide a tool similar to "Apple Software Update" that notifies the user about all available updates, and installs them automatically.

Is there a solution for Eclipse-RCP applications / p2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for [p2 update rcp](https://www.google.com/webhp?output=search&q=p2%20update%20rcp), and the first result is [Adding Self-Update to an RCP Application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application)

Comment: This does not answer my question. I'm already using p2 for updating my individual RCP applications. The questions refers to updating several RCP applications at once.

Comment: OK. That takes a little more work, but can be done. Unfortunately, there are ano easy to follow cook book for this :-) Basically, you must open the p2 director for each of the applications in turn and update them in much the same way as you use in the link above. You "just" need to know the root directory of each of the applications...